# PHP Login Validation

Tags: php

For some web development practice, I decided to make a dropbox-like site where users would login with a username and password and, assuming the combination is correct, would have access to a file uploader interface as well as a way to retrieve their files.  I have something that works, but I have run into one problem.  As soon as the user submits their username and password, the page is reloaded (this is fine) with the new php code, however, the URL changes slightly to where it reveals both the username and the password.  Can someone tell me how to prevent this from happening?

Here is the index.php file:

```
<?php
  function checkCredentials()
  {
    if($_GET && $_GET["username"]=="kwaugh" && $_GET["password"]=="password")
  {
?>

    <html>
        <head>
                <title>File Storage</title>
                    <style>
                        body{font-size:.85em ;font-family:Arial;}
                    </style>
        </head>

        <body>
            <center>
                <br>Please select the file that you would like to upload:<br><br>
                    <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                        <input type="file" name="filename"/>
                        <input type="submit" value="Upload" />
                    </form>
            </center>
        </body>
    </html>
    <?php
        if ($_FILES)
        {
            $name = $_FILES['filename']['name'];
            move_uploaded_file($_FILES['filename']['tmp_name'], $name);
            if(file_exists($name))
            {
                ?>
                <html>
                    <body>
                        <div style="color:red; font-size:2em; font-family:Arial">
                            <center>The file has been successfully uploaded <br />Click <a href="getFiles.php">here</a> to go to your uploaded files</center>
                        </div>
                    </body>
                </html>

                <?php
            }
            else
            {
                    ?>
                    <html>
                        <body>
                            <div style="color:red; font-size:2em; font-family:Arial">
                                <center>Well crap, something went wrong.  The file could not be uploaded :'( </center>
                            </div>
                        </body>
                    </html>

                    <?php
            }
    }
    die();
}
elseif($_GET && $_GET["username"]!=="kwaugh" || $_GET && $_GET["password"]!=="password")
{
    ?>
    <script>
        alert("You have entered an incorrect username/password combination");
    </script>

    <?php
}
}
checkCredentials();
?>
<html>
<head>
    <title>File Storage</title>
</head>

<body> <br /><br />
    <center>
        <img src="elephant.jpg">
        <form name="credentials">
            Please enter your username and password to upload files: <br     />
            Username: <input type="text" name="username"><br />
            Password: <input type="password" name="password"><br />
            <input type="submit" value="Submit" >
        </form>
        <br />Or click <a href="getFiles.php">here</a> to access stored files.
    </center>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `if($_GET` --- what's this for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `POST` for your `credentials` form.  By default, the `method` is `GET` which will append the parameters in the `URL`. Obviously, this means checking variables in the `$_POST` array instead of the `$_GET` array.

If I can give another suggestion, I would split the application in multiple files. You shouldn't have the login and the upload interface in the same script, otherwise you will have major problems scaling up your application.

- As you add pages, it will be almost impossible to know which part of the script should run and using which parameters and outputting what `html`
- You will need to pass a "state" to the page so that you internally know what the user is trying to do - spreading the logic over multiple `php` files would make it easier to do.
- The file will grow a lot, making it harder for you to understand what's actually getting executed, making it harder for you to debug
- If you ever start working with other developers, it would be more "developer friendly" to break the features in separate `php` files to minimize conflicts when editing the files

A lot of web applications will be split in multiple pages (often implemented in a [controller](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller)) where you would have the following:

- `Welcome Page` (landing page, allow to log in, allow sign in, display information about your product)
- `Authentication Page` (validate log in then redirect to the Profile page, show the sign in form, validate it, create new users, etc...)
- `Profile Page` (for a logged in user, display his information)

To this you should probably add a `File Management` page that shows all files owned by a user, allows him to add / delete pages, etc...

Comment: @NullPointer while I agree, there's so much that will go wrong that it's hard to explain :)

Comment: @NullPointer any better now?

Comment: Thanks a bunch!  I have one more question though.  Now that I am using POST instead of GET, the site automatically takes me back to the sign in part of the page after each upload.  How can I make it stay in the uploader interface after an upload?

Comment: @kwaugh this was my points when saying you should split the application in multiple files... you will have to use a `hidden` form field to pass a "state" so that your `PHP` knows to stay in the upload form. If you had multiple files you wouldn't have to do this

Comment: @kwaugh I'm sorry but I'm not sure what you mean?

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
<form name="credentials" method="post">
```

and

```
if($_POST && $_POST["username"]=="kwaugh" && $_POST["password"]=="password")
```

Comment: What do you mean by `if($_POST` ?

Comment: @zerkms jw... why are you commenting like this on everyone's post? The OP was asking how to hide the username and password from the URL query string, which we have answered.

Comment: I'm asking particularly about first condition in the `if` in your answer `if($_POST && ` <--- what does this mean?

Comment: @zerkms Oh. I think that it is pretty pointless, as it may be a tautology. `if (empty($_POST))` might be better.

Comment: `empty($_POST)` makes no sense as well :-)

Comment: `if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST')` should be used instead of `if ($_POST)` I suppose.

Answer (score 1):

Use `POST` in your form and `$_POST` in your PHP code.

`<form name="credentials" method="post" action="whatever-page.php">`

and

`if ($_POST["username"]=="kwaugh" && $_POST["password"]=="password")`

Comment: What do you mean by `if ($_POST` ?

Comment: `if ($_POST ...` really shouldn't be used and it was me being lazy copying and pasting his code.  `$_POST` being a superglobal is always set and is like saying `if (1)`.  I have edited my post to remove the reference.

Comment: @SenorAmor i suspect about always true `if($_POST){
    echo 'helo';
    
    }` not echoing anything

Comment: @NullPointer - You are correct.  I (incorrectly) assumed that since they are global in scope, that they are also always set.  It appears this is not the case.

Comment: Thanks, this makes perfect sense.  I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

change the login `<form>` to have a method of POST

`<form method="POST" name="credentials">`

Also, consider breaking up your web site into multiple .php files - you can't have everything in one file as it becomes unmanagable for all but the most simple sites.